# Multiple sampling inside an R function

Tags: r, function, dataframe, statistical-sampling

I am trying to make a function that in the end will run multiple machine learning algorithms on my data set. I have the first little bit of my function below and a small sample of data.

The problem i am running into is with sampling my data into four different data frames and then applying them to the given functions. Here on the first function i am testing the data runs threw the logistic regression model but on the output it uses all the data for that model and not just 1/4 of the data frame df as i am intending. I checked with <<- to see what kind of data is being passed threw and it sends a data set that is 1/4 of the data frame df that i am looking for. Question why douse it pass to my global environment the right way but not my regression function and how would i correct this?

Data:

```
zeroFac <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)

goal <- c(8.412055,  7.528869,  8.699681, 10.478752,  9.210440, 10.308986, 10.126671, 11.002117, 10.308986,  7.090910, 10.819798,  7.824446,  8.612685,
7.601402, 10.126671,  7.313887,  5.993961,  7.313887,  8.517393, 12.611541)

City_Pop <- c( 11.64613, 11.64613, 11.64613, 11.64613, 11.64613, 11.64613, 11.64613, 11.64613, 11.64613, 11.64613, 11.64613, 11.64613, 11.64613, 11.64613,
11.64613, 11.64613, 11.64613, 11.64613, 11.64613, 11.64613)

df <- data.frame(zeroFac,goal,City_Pop)
```

Function:

```
forestModel <- function(eq1, ...){

  #making our origenal data frame
  train <- data.frame(cbind(...))

  ################

    #splitting into 4 data sets
    set.seed(123)

    ss <- sample(1:4, size = nrow(train), replace=TRUE, prob = c(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25))

    t1 <- train[ss==1,]
    t2 <- train[ss==2,]
    t3 <- train[ss==3,]
    t4 <- train[ss==4,]

  ################

  m <- glm(eq1, family = binomial(link = 'logit'), data = t1)
  summary(m)

}

eq1 <- df$zeroFac ~ df$goal + df$City_Pop


forestModel(eq1, df$zeroFac, df$goal, df$City_Pop)
```

Comment: In the output of the logistic regression it tells me that it is using all observations not just a quarter of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the formula and name the columns of the train dataset in the function.
The equation changes from `eq1 <- df$zeroFac ~ df$goal + df$City_Pop` to `eq1 <- zeroFac ~ goal + City_Pop`. Otherwise it also contains the call to the dataframe and not just to the column names. And after binding the train-data together, you have to name their columns, so the glm function knows which columns you are reffering to in the equation.

```
 forestModel <- function(eq1, ...){

  #making our origenal data frame

  train <- data.frame(cbind(...))
  colNames <- colnames(data.frame(...))
  coln <- do.call(cbind, lapply(X = strsplit(colNames, "\\."), FUN = function(X) X[[2]]))
  colnames(train) <- coln

  ################

  #splitting into 4 data sets
  set.seed(123)

  ss <- sample(1:4, size = nrow(train), replace=TRUE, prob = c(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25))

  t1 <- train[ss==1,]
  ################

  m <- glm(eq1, family = binomial(link = 'logit'), data = t1)
  summary(m)
}

eq1 <- zeroFac ~ goal + City_Pop
forestModel(eq1, df$zeroFac, df$goal, df$City_Pop)
```

Comment: You are correct about the mistake. But, it still would not give the correct answer. See my answer below.

Comment: I think it do gives the correct result.  Checking the deviance.resid of the summary gives me less than 20 elements (Less than the original data.frame)

Comment: I didn't notice `colnames(train) <- c("zeroFac", "goal", "City_Pop")`  when I made the comment. I agree - it should work.  I  think the following statement is not true **Otherwise it also contains the call to the dataframe and not just to the column names.**  Even if you had used the formula correctly, as in `eq1 <- zeroFac ~ goal + City_Pop`, it will still use the data in the global environment.

Comment: A problem though arises. as i am using ... how would you change the column names if one were to add new variables to the equation without changing the function?

Comment: @Suren. You can try out with both formula equations, once with `df$...` and once only the column names. The outputs will be different. @Clinton. I am trying to figure that out, although I am not working a lot with the ellipsis function.

Comment: @ClintonWoods I edited my answer. It finds out the column names without the need to give them explicitly as function argument.

Answer (score 2):

In `train`, the column names are not what you expect ("zeroFac", "goal" and "City_Pop") them to be; they are "X1", "X2" and "X3".

According to the `glm` help, when the variables in the formula are not available in the data, they are taken from the `environment(formula)`. Hence, it is using the data in the global environment - where the formula is created.

From the `?glm`

> data   an optional data frame, list or environment (or object coercible
>   by as.data.frame to a data frame) containing the variables in the
>   model. If not found in data, the variables are taken from
>   `environment(formula)`, typically the environment from which `glm` is
>   called.

Your formula is also incorrect. It should be of the form `eq1 <- zeroFac ~ goal + City_Pop`. But, correcting that alone would NOT fix your problem.

**EDIT**

One option would be to pass the names of the variable separately, as in

```
forestModel <- function(eq1, colnam, ...) {

  train <- data.frame(cbind(...))
  colnames(train) <- colnam

  # splitting the data
  set.seed(123)

  ss <- sample(1:4, size = nrow(train), replace=TRUE, 
                    prob = c(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25))

  t1 <- train[ss==1,]

  m <- glm(eq1, family = binomial(link = 'logit'), data = t1)
  summary(m)
}

eq1 <- zeroFac ~ goal + City_Pop
colnam <- c("zeroFac", "goal", "City_Pop")

forestModel(eq1, colnam, df$zeroFac, df$goal, df$City_Pop)

# Call:
#   glm(formula = eq1, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = t1)
# 
# Deviance Residuals: 
#   2           4           5           8          11          16  
# 9.915e-06   2.110e-08  -1.080e-05  -2.110e-08   2.110e-08   2.110e-08  
# 20  
# 6.739e-06  
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept)    -960.87 2187192.38       0        1
# goal             12.32   41237.80       0        1
# City_Pop         74.28  166990.04       0        1
# 
# (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
# Null deviance: 8.3758e+00  on 6  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 2.6043e-10  on 4  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 6
# Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25
```